# How to apply a function to every group in a data.frame and place the result vector to a column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to forecast values in a long format dataframe. My data.frame has three groups in the column `class`, "detached", "semidetached" and "block". Columns `n`, `m2`, and `m3` are empty for the years 2005–2019, and for years 2020–2100 data is available.

Preferably using `dplyr`, how do I apply my custom forecast function to the columns `n`, `m2`, and `m3`, for all data.frame groups, and receive the values for 2005–2019? I work around this problem but I feel there is a one dplyr command solution to this.

My forecast function works exactly like Microsoft Excel's `FORECAST.LINEAR`, code below.

This is the dataset before any forecasting:

```
> dput(head(buildings_with_past, n = 30))
structure(list(year = 2005:2034, class = c("detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached"), classcode = c("011", 
"011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", 
"011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", 
"011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", 
"011", "011"), datasource = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", 
"officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", 
"officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", 
"officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata"
), n = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 154L, 789L, 888L, 510L, 407L, 236L, 925L, 168L, 693L, 
907L, 919L, 588L, 961L, 798L, 587L), m2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 79134L, 2665L, 98236L, 
30286L, 49899L, 93876L, 63993L, 86798L, 9401L, 99185L, 26131L, 
95172L, 79878L, 60798L, 29232L), m3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 172673L, 268031L, 487788L, 
921158L, 358765L, 435405L, 956259L, 397177L, 342335L, 893231L, 
220235L, 741390L, 110456L, 876053L, 926904L)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")

head(buildings_with_past, n = 30)
   year    class classcode   datasource   n    m2     m3
1  2005 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
2  2006 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
3  2007 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
4  2008 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
5  2009 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
6  2010 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
7  2011 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
8  2012 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
9  2013 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
10 2014 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
11 2015 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
12 2016 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
13 2017 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
14 2018 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
15 2019 detached       011         <NA>  NA    NA     NA
16 2020 detached       011 officialdata  98  5590 721175
17 2021 detached       011 officialdata 272 79296 424402
18 2022 detached       011 officialdata 307 20035 381664
19 2023 detached       011 officialdata 238 42911 367112
20 2024 detached       011 officialdata 901 54418 391759
21 2025 detached       011 officialdata 707 27230 771767
22 2026 detached       011 officialdata 336 93473 429353
23 2027 detached       011 officialdata 360 75397 482743
24 2028 detached       011 officialdata 715 22536 982089
25 2029 detached       011 officialdata 525 88036 913973
26 2030 detached       011 officialdata 599 36496 683554
27 2031 detached       011 officialdata 308  4637 620769
28 2032 detached       011 officialdata 892 68470 344725
29 2033 detached       011 officialdata 346 28548   8051
30 2034 detached       011 officialdata  36 50209 696974
```

Here is the code to get `buildings_with_past`:

```
# This is the forecast function I am working with
forecast.linear <- function(pred_x, known_ys, known_xs) {
  
  # This function performs the functionality of Excel's FORECAST.LINEAR. In our
  # context, pred_x is the year of forecasting, known_ys is the dependent range 
  # of data and known_xs the independent array or range of data (range of years).
  
  pred_x <- as.numeric(pred_x)
  known_ys <- as.numeric(known_ys)
  known_xs <- as.numeric(known_xs)
  
  x <- data.frame(known_xs = pred_x)
  relation <- lm(known_ys ~ known_xs)
  result <- predict(relation, x) %>%
    as.numeric()
  
  return(result)
}

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

# Set up an example dataframe
future_years <- seq(from = "2020", to = "2100")
past_years <- seq(from = "2005", to = "2019")
buildingclass <- c("detached", "semidetached", "block")
classcode <- c("011", "012", "013")

buildings <- data.frame(
  year = future_years,
  class = rep(buildingclass, each = length(future_years)),
  classcode = rep(classcode, each = length(future_years)),
  datasource = "officialdata")

buildings$n <- sample(1000, size = nrow(buildings), replace = TRUE)
buildings$m2 <- sample(100000, size = nrow(buildings), replace = TRUE)
buildings$m3 <- sample(1000000, size = nrow(buildings), replace = TRUE)

buildings_with_past <- buildings %>% 
  dplyr::group_modify(
    ~ tibble::add_row(
      ., 
      year = past_years,
      .before = 1)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(c(class, classcode), .direction = "downup")
```

Here is an unwieldy example how the function `forecast.linear` would look like for one group ("detached"):

```
# a forecast.linear example 
detached_n <- 
  buildings %>% 
  dplyr::filter(year %in% future_years & classcode == "011") %>% 
  pull(n)

detached_m2 <- 
  buildings %>% 
  dplyr::filter(year %in% future_years & classcode == "011") %>% 
  pull(m2)

detached_m3 <- 
  buildings %>% 
  dplyr::filter(year %in% future_years & classcode == "011") %>% 
  pull(m3)
  
# set up a forecast dataframe to be bind to the original dataframe buildings
forecastlinear_exampledf <- data.frame(
  year = past_years,
  class = rep(buildingclass[1], each = length(past_years)),
  classcode = rep(classcode[1], each = length(past_years)),
  n = sapply(past_years, forecast.linear, detached_n, future_years),
  m2 = sapply(past_years, forecast.linear, detached_m2, future_years),
  m3 = sapply(past_years, forecast.linear, detached_m3, future_years),
  datasource = "forecast"
)
buildings <- rbind(forecastlinear_exampledf, buildings)
```

This is how the final forecast result should look like:

```
> dput(head(buildings, n = 30))
structure(list(year = 2005:2034, class = c("detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", "detached", 
"detached", "detached", "detached", "detached"), classcode = c("011", 
"011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", 
"011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", 
"011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", "011", 
"011", "011"), n = c(611.596770551039, 611.0842366757, 610.571702800361, 
610.059168925023, 609.546635049684, 609.034101174345, 608.521567299006, 
608.009033423668, 607.496499548329, 606.98396567299, 606.471431797651, 
605.958897922313, 605.446364046974, 604.933830171635, 604.421296296296, 
154, 789, 888, 510, 407, 236, 925, 168, 693, 907, 919, 588, 961, 
798, 587), m2 = c(57179.0030864197, 57102.6012345679, 57026.199382716, 
56949.7975308642, 56873.3956790123, 56796.9938271605, 56720.5919753086, 
56644.1901234568, 56567.7882716049, 56491.3864197531, 56414.9845679012, 
56338.5827160494, 56262.1808641975, 56185.7790123457, 56109.3771604938, 
79134, 2665, 98236, 30286, 49899, 93876, 63993, 86798, 9401, 
99185, 26131, 95172, 79878, 60798, 29232), m3 = c(498162.631925625, 
498521.806519121, 498880.981112617, 499240.155706113, 499599.330299609, 
499958.504893105, 500317.6794866, 500676.854080096, 501036.028673592, 
501395.203267088, 501754.377860584, 502113.55245408, 502472.727047576, 
502831.901641072, 503191.076234568, 172673, 268031, 487788, 921158, 
358765, 435405, 956259, 397177, 342335, 893231, 220235, 741390, 
110456, 876053, 926904), datasource = c("forecast", "forecast", 
"forecast", "forecast", "forecast", "forecast", "forecast", "forecast", 
"forecast", "forecast", "forecast", "forecast", "forecast", "forecast", 
"forecast", "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", 
"officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", 
"officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata", 
"officialdata", "officialdata", "officialdata")), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")

head(buildings, n = 30)
   year    class classcode        n       m2       m3   datasource
1  2005 detached       011 489.8249 48412.15 472867.2     forecast
2  2006 detached       011 488.6909 48342.14 473874.5     forecast
3  2007 detached       011 487.5570 48272.13 474881.8     forecast
4  2008 detached       011 486.4230 48202.12 475889.2     forecast
5  2009 detached       011 485.2890 48132.11 476896.5     forecast
6  2010 detached       011 484.1551 48062.10 477903.9     forecast
7  2011 detached       011 483.0211 47992.09 478911.2     forecast
8  2012 detached       011 481.8871 47922.09 479918.6     forecast
9  2013 detached       011 480.7532 47852.08 480925.9     forecast
10 2014 detached       011 479.6192 47782.07 481933.3     forecast
11 2015 detached       011 478.4852 47712.06 482940.6     forecast
12 2016 detached       011 477.3513 47642.05 483947.9     forecast
13 2017 detached       011 476.2173 47572.04 484955.3     forecast
14 2018 detached       011 475.0833 47502.03 485962.6     forecast
15 2019 detached       011 473.9494 47432.02 486970.0     forecast
16 2020 detached       011  98.0000  5590.00 721175.0 officialdata
17 2021 detached       011 272.0000 79296.00 424402.0 officialdata
18 2022 detached       011 307.0000 20035.00 381664.0 officialdata
19 2023 detached       011 238.0000 42911.00 367112.0 officialdata
20 2024 detached       011 901.0000 54418.00 391759.0 officialdata
21 2025 detached       011 707.0000 27230.00 771767.0 officialdata
22 2026 detached       011 336.0000 93473.00 429353.0 officialdata
23 2027 detached       011 360.0000 75397.00 482743.0 officialdata
24 2028 detached       011 715.0000 22536.00 982089.0 officialdata
25 2029 detached       011 525.0000 88036.00 913973.0 officialdata
26 2030 detached       011 599.0000 36496.00 683554.0 officialdata
27 2031 detached       011 308.0000  4637.00 620769.0 officialdata
28 2032 detached       011 892.0000 68470.00 344725.0 officialdata
29 2033 detached       011 346.0000 28548.00   8051.0 officialdata
30 2034 detached       011  36.0000 50209.00 696974.0 officialdata
```

Comment: Typo: `futureyears` vs `future_years`

Comment: One way I've done this is by nesting the data within each group, and using broom to apply to each data set: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Comment: It will save others time and reduce ambiguity if you can share the output of running `dput(head(buildings_with_past, n = 30))` instead of the printed appearance of that data.

Comment: Fixed typos and added `dput` subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is as straight-forward as:

```r
buildings %>%
  group_by(class, classcode) %>%
  summarize(
    year = pastyears, 
    n = sapply(pastyears, forecast.linear, n, futureyears), 
    m2 = sapply(pastyears, forecast.linear, m2, futureyears), 
    m3 = sapply(pastyears, forecast.linear, m3, futureyears), 
    datasource = "forecast"
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 45 × 7
#    class classcode  year     n     m2      m3 datasource
#    <chr> <chr>     <int> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     
#  1 block 013        2005  569. 60683. 373348. forecast  
#  2 block 013        2006  568. 60595. 374999. forecast  
#  3 block 013        2007  567. 60507. 376649. forecast  
#  4 block 013        2008  566. 60419. 378300. forecast  
#  5 block 013        2009  566. 60332. 379950. forecast  
#  6 block 013        2010  565. 60244. 381601. forecast  
#  7 block 013        2011  564. 60156. 383252. forecast  
#  8 block 013        2012  563. 60068. 384902. forecast  
#  9 block 013        2013  563. 59980. 386553. forecast  
# 10 block 013        2014  562. 59892. 388203. forecast  
# # … with 35 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

In fact, it can be reduced a little since you're doing the "same thing" with each of the three columns `n`, `m2`, and `m3`:

```r
buildings %>%
  group_by(class, classcode) %>%
  summarize(
    year = pastyears,
    across(c(n, m2, m3),
           ~ sapply(pastyears, forecast.linear, ., futureyears)),
    datasource = "forecast"
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: This is it, thank you. I needed slight editing to make my code work with your answer:    `across(c(n, m2, m3), ~ sapply(year, forecast.linear, ., future_years))`